# Maintaining order of iteration on a Hash Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.8.7

This is a simple homework assignment....

Given a hash that looks like this:

```
cost_of_groceries = {
"milk" => 3.50,
"egg" => 1.50,
"broccolli" => 0.75
}
```

I want to print out which groceries are less than $2 and which groceries are more than $2. This would be a sample output:

```
milk is more than $2
eggs is less than $2
broccolli is less than $2
```

Not a problem, but this is not printing in the correct order using Ruby 1.8.7.

My code:

```
cost_of_groceries.each do |x,y|
  if y > 2
    puts "#{x} is more than $2"
  else
    puts "#{x} is less than $2"
  end
end
```

This is what I get:

```
broccolli is less than $2
egg is less than $2
milk is more than $2
=> {"broccolli"=>0.75, "egg"=>1.5, "milk"=>3.5}
```

I realize pre-1.9 Ruby does not maintain the order of iteration on a Hash, and I know I can just use different version to solve this, but I was hoping to dig into this and learn an alternate method for pre-1.9.3.  I never know when it might come in handy.

This is a similar post: "[Ruby maintain Hash insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040617/ruby-maintain-hash-insertion-order)"

Comment: One word: Arrays. Also, 1.8.7 is deprecated and unsupported. Learning how to use it probably *won't* come in handy.

Comment: 1.8.7 might be deprecated, but it's sure installed on a lot of systems, and it's not going away just because it's unsupported. We've got hundreds of machines with 1.8.6 on them and they're not going to be upgraded, so knowing these sort of tricks can come in very handy. Plus, knowing this can be applicable to other languages, besides Ruby. It isn't a one-to-one match, but that's similar to how I'd do it in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby prior to 1.9 didn't maintain the "insertion" order of hashes. Here's a way to force a known order, without relying on sorting:

```
BASE_COST = 2.0

COST_OF_GROCERIES = {
  "milk"      => 3.50,
  "egg"       => 1.50,
  "broccolli" => 0.75
}

DESIRED_ORDER = %w[milk egg broccolli]
COST_OF_GROCERIES.values_at(*DESIRED_ORDER) # => [3.5, 1.5, 0.75]
```

That returns just the values, in their desired order.

Here's how to process the hash in that same order:

```
DESIRED_ORDER.each do |k|
  lt_gt = COST_OF_GROCERIES[k] > BASE_COST ? 'more' : 'less'
  puts '%s is %s than %0.2f' % [k, lt_gt, BASE_COST]
end
# >> milk is more than 2.00
# >> egg is less than 2.00
# >> broccolli is less than 2.00
```

---

Here's another way to look at it...

Enumerable's `zip` lets us join two arrays' elements, interweaving them:

```
DESIRED_ORDER.zip(COST_OF_GROCERIES.values_at(*DESIRED_ORDER)) # => [["milk", 3.5], ["egg", 1.5], ["broccolli", 0.75]]
```

We can pass the output from `zip` to `map` to add in whether the prices is "more" or "less":

```
groceries = DESIRED_ORDER.zip(COST_OF_GROCERIES.values_at(*DESIRED_ORDER)).map{ |grocery, price| 
  [
    grocery, 
    price, 
    price > BASE_COST ? 'more' : 'less'
  ] 
} 
groceries # => [["milk", 3.5, "more"], ["egg", 1.5, "less"], ["broccolli", 0.75, "less"]]
```

Look at the contents of `groceries`: An array-of-arrays is exactly the sort of data you'd want to pass to a view if you were rendering a web-page using ERB or Haml.

Then we can generate some output strings and print them:

```
puts groceries.map{ |ary|
  '%s, at $%.2f is %s than $%0.2f' % [*ary, BASE_COST]
}
# >> milk, at $3.50 is more than $2.00
# >> egg, at $1.50 is less than $2.00
# >> broccolli, at $0.75 is less than $2.00
```

Using a format-string is akin to an ERB or Haml template. This is just a couple steps away from how ERB/Haml got their start.

I broke the above into smaller steps, but the actual process could be written:

```
puts DESIRED_ORDER.zip(COST_OF_GROCERIES.values_at(*DESIRED_ORDER)).map{ |grocery, price| 
  [
    grocery, 
    price, 
    price > BASE_COST ? 'more' : 'less'
  ] 
}.map{ |ary|
  '%s, at $%.2f is %s than $%0.2f' % [*ary, BASE_COST]
}
# >> milk, at $3.50 is more than $2.00
# >> egg, at $1.50 is less than $2.00
# >> broccolli, at $0.75 is less than $2.00
```

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate you breaking it down for me.  Consequently I now have some new syntactic sugar that I am excited to play with.

Comment: I added a bit more. Ruby's very flexible, and we can write functionally, by chaining, or more procedurally. There are times and places for either, so I let readability be my guide quite often, unless one will use the CPU better.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have been able to mashup:  it works but violates the context of homework question:

```
hash={}

hash.instance_eval do
  def []=(key,val)
    ordered_keys << key
    super(key,val)
  end

  def ordered_keys
    @ordered_keys ||= []
  end

  def each_in_order(&block)
    ordered_keys.each do |key|
      yield(key, self[key])
    end
  end
end


hash['milk'] = 3.50
hash['egg'] = 1.50
hash['broccolli'] = 0.75



hash.each_in_order do |key, val|
  if val > 2
    puts "#{key} is more Than $2"
  else
    puts "#{key} is less than $2"
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to iterate a hash with an arbitrary ordering, the best approach is usually to specify the order with an array of keys and loop over that. So you'd have an array like `['eggs', 'milk', 'broccoli']`, and you'd access the hash object for the appropriate key.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be an interesting exercise to maintain order by subclassing `Hash`.  `[]=(other)` can be used to add or change elements, and `delete` can be used to remove them, but I have not attempted to override other hash methods that add or delete elements:

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def initialize(*vals)
    pairs =  vals.each_slice(2).to_a
    @keys = pairs.map(&:first)
    pairs.each_with_object(super()) {|(k,v), h| h[k] = v}
  end

  def []=(key,val)
    @keys << key unless @keys.include?(key)
    super
  end

  def delete(key)
    @keys.delete(key)
    super
  end

  def print_prices(cutoff)
    @keys.each do |k|
      if self[k] < cutoff
         puts "#{k} is less than %0.2f" % [cutoff]
      else
         puts "#{k} is at least %0.2f" % [cutoff]      
      end    
    end
  end  
end

h = MyHash.new("milk", 3.50, "egg", 1.50, "broccolli", 0.75)
  # => {"milk"=>3.5, "egg"=>1.5, "broccolli"=>0.75}

h.print_prices(2.00)         
milk is at least 2.00
egg is less than 2.00
broccolli is less than 2.00

h["fish"] = 2.00
h["egg"] = 2.10
h.delete("milk")

h.print_prices(2.00)         
egg is at least 2.00
broccolli is less than 2.00
fish is at least 2.00
```